# Imputation of NaNs on count variables using a Poisson's regression

Tags: numpy, statsmodels, imputation, poisson

I have a Pandas dataframe with variables that are all counts (integer data, such as count of pieces of fruit ingested on average, count of hours slept on average, etc). Here is a dummy dataset that is similar for the sake of the MRE:

### Dummy dataset (copy&paste directly)

```
# Dummy dataset simulating my conditions
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Define the ranges and number of unique values for each variable
range_0_24 = 25
range_0_30 = 31
range_0_4 = 5

total_rows = 20000
rows_without_nans = 400
rows_with_nans = total_rows - rows_without_nans

num_columns = 14

# Generate data for the rows without NaNs
data_without_nans = {
    f'var_{i}': np.random.randint(0, range_0_24, rows_without_nans)
    if i < 5 else np.random.randint(0, range_0_30, rows_without_nans)
    if i < 10 else np.random.randint(0, range_0_4, rows_without_nans)
    for i in range(num_columns)
}

# Create DataFrame for rows without NaNs
df_without_nans = pd.DataFrame(data_without_nans)

# Generate data for the rows with at least one NaN
data_with_nans = {
    f'var_{i}': np.random.randint(0, range_0_24, rows_with_nans)
    if i < 5 else np.random.randint(0, range_0_30, rows_with_nans)
    if i < 10 else np.random.randint(0, range_0_4, rows_with_nans)
    for i in range(num_columns)
}

# Introduce NaNs randomly in the DataFrame
for i in range(num_columns):
    rows_to_introduce_nans = np.random.choice(df_without_nans.index, rows_with_nans, replace=True)
    df_without_nans.loc[rows_to_introduce_nans, f'var_{i}'] = np.nan

# Concatenate the dataframes to create the final dataset
df = pd.concat([df_without_nans, pd.DataFrame(data_with_nans)])

# Shuffle the rows in the final dataset
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I need to impute the missing values on all variables (that is, get rid of all NaNs) by applying a Poisson regression, and I came up with this code... but it is not working as expected because it is not introducing any new values (the total NaNs of `df` are the same as the total NaNs of `df2`) and I cannot tell where the mistakes are. Or how else to code it.

These are the steps I tried to follow, you'll see them in my code snippet below:

1. Separate data into two dataframes: one that contains the complete rows and other that contains the rows with missing data
2. Train a Poisson regressor on each column on the complete data dataframe
3. Use this regressor to predict the values on the missing data dataframe

This is the code that I came up with:

### Actual code (copy&paste directly)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Split data into complete data and data with missing values
complete_data = df.dropna(subset=df.columns.values.tolist())
missing_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

# Generate a copy of the df where I'll be imputing the values
df2 = df.copy()

for col in df.columns.tolist():
    
    X = complete_data.drop(columns=[col])
    
    # Add a constant for the intercept
    X = sm.add_constant(X)  
    y = complete_data[col]
    
    # Remove rows with NaN or infinite values from the data
    mask = (~np.isinf(y)) & (~np.isnan(y))
    X = X[mask]
    y = y[mask]
    
    poisson_model = sm.Poisson(y, X).fit()
    
    X_missing = missing_data.drop(columns=[col])
    X_missing = sm.add_constant(X_missing)

    predicted_values = poisson_model.predict(X_missing)
    
    # Round the predicted values
    predicted_values = np.round(predicted_values)
    
    # Set negative predictions to zero
    predicted_values[predicted_values < 0] = 0

    # Fill missing values in the original df for the specific column
    df2.loc[missing_data.index, col] = predicted_values.values
```

What is my error?

Comment: "but it is not working as expected" What isn't working? Are you getting an error? If not, how do the actual results compare to the expected results?

Comment: @jared it is not working as expected because it is not introducing any new values (the total NaNs of `df` are the same as the total NaNs of `df2`), I would expect `df2` to not have NaNs at all after executing the last snippet of code. I added this to the post for the sake of clarity, thanks